# Using XPath to show hidden data

Tags: import.io

This might be easy for most of you but this has me stumped for several days now. I'm currently using import.io to create crawlers and I'm still getting a grasp on using xpath overrides.

I want to know the best way for me to get the data that only shows up when you click on the button.

Here's an example of the page:
http://www.timeout.com/newyork/restaurants/agave#tab_panel_2

And here's the xpath:
//*[@id="tab___content_2"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/a[2]/span[2]

By using the xpath, I get "Call Venue" but I'm looking for the phone number that only shows up if the button is clicked.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following XPATH would do the work for you:
//*[@id="tab___content_2"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/a[2]/@href

Comment: Thanks! This works great! I just needed to use regex to just take the phone number .

Comment: Would be great if you can share regex for others :-)

Comment: Yeah sure! Here's the regex I used so that I get only the phone number bit: (\d+.+\d)